# Flask Stripe Checkout dynamic prices SessionID error

Tags: javascript, python, flask, stripe-payments

I've been using https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/migrating-prices#server-side-code-for-inline-items and https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/accept-a-payment as well as other guides/SO posts as a guide.

The checkout button in payments.html page doesn't work; nothing happens on the page.
In the Flask's /payment function, I have been able to print out the session/session.id fine.
I have tried passing the session and the session.id to the payments.html page, but neither has worked. The {{price}} on payments.html works fine.

What am I overlooking/messing up here to get the Checkout page working?

base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Stripe Checkout</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='main.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='bootstrap.min.css') }}">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    
    <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      {% block content %}
      {% endblock %}
    </div>
    {% block scripts %}
    {% endblock %}
  </body>
</html>
```

Payments.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
  <div>
    <h1>Cost</h1>
    <h2>Pay ${{price}}</h2>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="checkout">Pay with Card</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="back">Back</button>
    
  </div>
  <div id="status">
    <br>
    <div class="alert alert-primary" id="alert" role="alert"></div>
  </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block scripts %}
  <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3"></script>
  <script>
    var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_...');

    var checkoutButton = document.querySelector('#checkout');
    checkoutButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
      stripe.redirectToCheckout({
        sessionId: {{sessionID}}
      });
    });
  </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Flask's /payment function

```
@app.route("/payment")
def payment():
    price = "50"
    session = session.Session().getSession(int(price)*100)
    sessionID = session.id
    print("SessionID:", sessionID)
    return render_template("payment.html", sessionID=sessionID, price=price)
```

Python Stripe file

```
import stripe

stripe.api_key = 'sk_test_...'

class Session:
  
    def __init__(self):
        pass
  
    def getSession(self, price):
        session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
          payment_method_types=['card'],
          line_items=[{
            'price_data': {
              'currency': 'usd',
              'product_data': {
                'name': 'blah',
              },
              'unit_amount': price,
            },
            'quantity': 1,
          }],
          mode='payment',
          success_url='https://example.com/success',
          cancel_url='https://example.com/cancel',
        )
      
        return session
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser?

Comment: @floatingLomas oh man, thanks, I didn't think to use the browser's console. Yeah, I figured it out, I have to use the session.id and have quotes around {{sessionID}}.

Comment: Glad you got it figured out! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @floatingLomas, I didn't think to use the browser's console. Yeah, I figured it out, I have to use the session.id and have quotes around {{sessionID}}.